# Set OnClickListener on Button in GroupAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to set an OnClickListener for a button inside of a GroupAdapter RecyclerView

My code:

```
class settings : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?, 
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false)

    val adapter = GroupAdapter<ViewHolder>()
    adapter.add(SettingTitle("Permissions"))
    adapter.add(SettingCardCarInfo())
        
    //FAILED METHOD #1
    view.btn_update_settings.setOnClickListener {
        Log.d("tahoma","")
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Your settings were updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    //FAILED METHOD #2
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener { v, settings_end ->
        Log.d("tahoma",v.id.toString())
     }

    view.settingsRecycler.adapter = adapter

    return view
    }}
```

---

```
class SettingEnd : Item<ViewHolder>() {
    override fun getLayout(): Int {
        return R.layout.settings_end
    }
    
    override fun bind(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {}
```

---

## What i've tried:

1 - Simply calling the onclick listener on the button, gives me a null call error

2 - Using the Adapter onclick listener did catch clicks, but ignored any clicks on clickable items (so no good for the button)

3 - Doing the same as #1 but through the "OnStart" method - didn't work since "view" wasn't callable inside that method

4 - Calling the onclick listener through the OnBind method of the viewholder - it did work (I was able to detect button clicks), but was unable to access needed data from other viewholders in the same adapter, that contain edittexts which I need to get to.

Any help at this point would be appriciated, solutions written in Kotlin syntex will be great

Answer (score 0):

Using a `RecyclerView` you need to set the click listener on the view inside the adapter like so:

```
class GroupAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {

    var onItemClick: (<Type Of Item>) -> Unit = {}

    fun createViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(<InflateViewHere>).apply {
            itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {
                onItemClick(getItem(adapterPosition))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your fragment set `onItemClick` to handle when the button is clicked